# Como converter px em vh e vw no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Eu quero converter px em vh e vw no JavaScript, como posso fazer isso?

exemplo
23px = resutado vh ou vw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É apenas uma questão de porcentagem:

```
var convertPx2 = {
  vh: function(px){
    px = parseFloat(px);
    var wh = $(window).height(); // captura a altura da viewport

    // faz a relação de  porcentagem dos pixels informados
    // com a altura da viewport
    return (px*100)/wh;
  },
  vw: function(px){
    px = parseFloat(px);
    var ww = $(window).width();  // captura a largura da viewport

    // faz a relação de  porcentagem dos pixels informados
    // com a largura da viewport
    return (px*100)/ww; 
  }
}
```

```js
var convertPx2 = {
 vh: function(px){
   px = parseFloat(px);
   var wh = $(window).height();
    
    return (px*100)/wh;
  },
 vw: function(px){
   px = parseFloat(px);
   var ww = $(window).width();
    
    return (px*100)/ww;
  }
}

console.log('400px em vw: ', convertPx2.vw(400));
console.log('400px em vh: ', convertPx2.vh(400));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Exelente soluçao, funcionou muito bem